# Переместить с блоков в низ

Tags: html, css

[image: картинка]

```
 <section class="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <div class="block2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="block1">
                        <div class="block_in_block">
                            <h1 class="About">About Us.</h1>
                            <span class="block_text">Analytics release series A financing launch party interaction design android angel investor. Vesting period social media sales conversion launch party rockstar incubator customer social proof graphical user interface technology supply chain.
                                Non-disclosure agreement rockstar creative partner network launch party social proof paradigm shift long tail influencer.
                                <p><p>Monetization        validation success. Seed round channels product
                                management.         Customer non-disclosure agreement strategy
                                android growth hacking ramen buyer.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="Focus">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <div class="block_text_2">
                        <h1>Our Focus</h1>
                        <p>We understand your requirement and provide quality works.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
.block1{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    width: 653px; /* Ширина слоя */
    height: 551px;
    margin: 65px 391px 226px 400px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Параметры тени */
    padding: 10px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
}
.block_in_block{
    width: 488px; /* Ширина слоя */
    height: 350px;
    margin: 95px 83px 106px 84px;
}
.About{
    margin: 0px 0px 48px 0px;
}
.block_text{
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}
.block2{
    position:absolute;
    width:  555px; /* Ширина слоя */
    height: 700px;
    border: 5px solid #AA8A84; /*  рамка */
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(77, 29, 29), rgb(85, 37, 39), rgb(93, 44, 50), rgb(100, 52, 60), rgb(108, 60, 70), rgb(116, 67, 81), rgb(124, 75, 91), rgb(132, 82, 102), rgb(140, 90, 112), rgb(147, 98, 122), rgb(155, 105, 133), rgb(163, 113, 143));
}
```

Делаю Лаборатоную
Почему `<section class="Focus">` лезат на блоки `<section class="about">`
Как сделать что бы они начиланалось с низу `<section class="about">`

Answer (score 1):

Происходит это из-за абсолютного позиционирования. Ознакомьтесь с данным материалом http://htmlbook.ru/css/position и внесите следующие правки в css код:

```
    .block1{
        /*position: absolute;*/  /*эту строку уберите */
        background-color: white;
        width: 653px; /* Ширина слоя */
        height: 551px;
        margin: 65px 391px 226px 400px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Параметры тени */
        padding: 10px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
    }

    .block2{
         /*position: absolute;*/  /*эту строку уберите */
        width:  555px; /* Ширина слоя */
        height: 700px;
        border: 5px solid #AA8A84; /*  рамка */
        background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(77, 29, 29), rgb(85, 37, 39), rgb(93, 44, 50), rgb(100, 52, 60), rgb(108, 60, 70), rgb(116, 67, 81), rgb(124, 75, 91), rgb(132, 82, 102), rgb(140, 90, 112), rgb(147, 98, 122), rgb(155, 105, 133), rgb(163, 113, 143));
    }

   .focus, .about {
     display:block;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding-top: 20px;
     padding-bottom: 20px;
   }
```